# JPA Hibernate errors in named queries

Tags: hibernate, jpa, named-query

What is wrong with this NamedQuery? Did not work on Hibernate 5 but worked on Openjpa  1.2.2

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "Dic_listDByVal", query = "SELECT d FROM Dict d "
                + " WHERE d.memory = m.memory and d.dic = :dic and (m.value LIKE :value)"
                + " ORDER BY d.sortOrder")
```

Comment: What is `m` here `m.memory`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have not defined `m( in m.memory)` here, meaning you must have missed a `JOIN` clause

Comment: Yeah, missing m, should look like:
@NamedQuery(name = "Dic_listDByVal", query = "SELECT d FROM Dict d, Mem m "
                + " WHERE d.memory = m.memory and d.dic = :dic and (m.value LIKE :value)"
                + " ORDER BY d.sortOrder")